# Can I ride on the beach with 32c tires?

Tags: tire, hybrid-bike, off-road, tyre-width

I have a hybrid bike (Merida Speeder 200) with 700x32c tires.
I've been using it on the road with great pleasure, but given the corona situation it's becoming quite crowded on the (nice) roads.

Therefore I'm looking for alternative paths. The beach is semi-nearby and has a wide flat strip of "hard" sand during low tide.

Can I ride on the hard sand with 32c tires?

Comment: Personally I wouldn’t take a bike on a beach because of the salt and possibility for corrosion

Comment: Came here to say what @ArgentiApparatus said.

Comment: I would be more worried about the sand, actually.

Comment: I would note that a 32mm tire is about the thinnest I would attempt beach riding with.

Comment: Maybe ride the bike *to* the beach, lock it up and then just walk/run on the beach instead?  Not sure how safe it is to lock up a bike where you're not nearby for a while where you live.  I wouldn't do it here due to high likelihood of theft.  Could walk with the bike to be on the safe side if the sand proves too difficult to ride on.  Either way, a good wash afterwards is probably a good idea as others have noted.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman it's fairly safe here, so certainly a possibility. However, I hate running and like biking so would prefer that mode of movement.

Comment: Wash bike very well afterwards. Brush into crevices and/or use a hose with as much pressure as available. Salt water is not an instant killer but it is a killer with time. Dirt and debris in crevices that hold it in pace "don't help".

Comment: Might be a follow-on question here - "should I ride my bike on the beach? And what are the pitfalls to watch out for?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While my initial attempt with lightly deflated tires was not a success (I could only bike 100 m before being exhausted) my second attempt went much better.

Based on your helpful answers, comments and suggestions I deflated my rear tire to 1.5 bar, and my front tire to 2 bar and rode at the waterline without much problems at an average speed of 20 km/h.

I was there 1.5 hours after low tide, but there was still plenty of compact sand. Also, it didn't really matter if I was riding on the wet sand at the edge of the water, or a few meters further inland on the drier compact sand, both required approximately the same perceived effort.
Loosened sand (e.g. after dogs have played there) and swathes of shells/seaweed required more effort, so I tried to avoid those.

For context: I use Continental Grand Prix 4 Season 700x32c tires, weigh around 80 kg and am not superfit, but can sustain 25-30 km/h on the road.

#### Conclusion

Based on my experience: yes, you can ride on the beach with 32c tires *if*:

- You deflate your tires significantly (to 1.5 - 2 bar)
- Ride during low tide on the compact sand

Comment: Try adjusting your track up/down the beach a little.  Ideally you want to be on the firm damp sand that is not actively wet/foamy.   Too soft/dry and you loose power, too wet and you loose power.  Your thighs will guide you to the sweet spot.  But there's no point on a beach where its easier than on a road.

Comment: What tires are you using?

Comment: You need very soft tyres. There are no pinch flats in sand. Cyclocross racers ride almost on their rims with their tubs. Certainly below 20 PSI. But I would not ride in the sand unless you have someone who cleans your bike for you often. The sand will get into your bearings and that is horrible

Comment: @TudeProductions OP did specify 32mm Conti Grand Prix 4 seasons, which are a slick durable road tire.

Comment: @WeiwenNg yes you are right those tires are pretty much a paved road only and possibly light gravel. Perhaps a more aggressive tire would be in order, but at that point your are starting to sacrifice on road performance.

Comment: @VladimirF I tested my tires today (they were still underinflated from my beach ride) and I measured around 4.5 bar (instead of the 6 I have on the road). I hope to test a lower pressure tomorrow and will report back. Regarding the sand: thank for the heads up. I guess I'll just take that as it is. In my experience bikes can handle quite a beating and can get replacement parts easily. Besides, I'm not planning to do this everyday or for long distances, hopefully that limits the damage.

Comment: 4.5 bar is insanely high. I ride my 38C tires around 2.5 bar on rough gravel and tree roots (tubeless, though). Cyclocross sand dunes racing happens below 1.5 bar.

Answer (score 8):

Yes on hard sand it should be fine. The problem is what if it is not hard or there are patches of dust. At that point it will be a bit more tricky. The good part is you are on a bike and on sand. So if you fall it is not a big deal, and if you find yourself getting stuck you can walk sections.

You may consider lowering your tire pressure too as that works for cars and fat bikes on loose terrain because it increases the contact patch (i.e. lowers the pounds per inch on the tire to the sand, which makes you less likely to dig into the sand).

Note - Depending on how often you ride in wet/sandy conditions you may want to proactively upgrade your bottom bracket bearing to a sealed one. I did on my Trek road bike which has a notoriously fragile bottom bracket bearing/seal. For your Merida it may not be much of an issue as long as you keep the area between the peddles and frame relatively clean on a regular basis.

Comment: ... and dust and wash the bicycle after each ride, as salt and sand are some of its worst enemies.

Comment: “i.e. lowers the pressure per inch” – that doesn't dimension-check. You can say it lowers the _force per square-inch_ (that's just what pressure is).

Answer (score 5):

I haven’t seen the beach, or tried to cycle on one. I have at least cycled through numerous sandpits, a common obstacle in cyclocross races (and traditional CX tires are 32-34mm wide).

I would guess that you mean the sand is somewhat compacted. You could certainly try it, but I would guess that the sand may not be compacted enough, and your tires might dig in to it. This would probably make it considerably harder to cycle through the sand.

I don’t know what your area is like, but many off-road trails with hard packed crushed limestone or gravel can easily be traversed on 32mm tires. The ones without loose gravel can even be ridden on traditional road bikes.

Answer (score 3):

Beach races are quite standard, but there's a difference between soft and hard. There is nothing very complicated about bringing a vehicle over sand, and no strict cut-off point.

However this is a very pure beach racing bike

https://www.koga.com/en/bikes/race/collection-2018/beachracer.htm

It's a 10kg racing/CX bike with discs and Schwalbe 62mm (2.35") Big One tyres

This tyre is very specifically designed for beach racing.

https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/mtb-reviews/schwalbe-big-one-2016

"The Schwalbe Big One is a mountain bike tire designed for beach racing. Because of the beach racing requirements, the Big One has a huge volume, minimal profile and an extremely low weight for its size. "

It might be easier to fit wide tyres to a MTB in that they usually have that kind of clearance, but 2"+ tyres are a minimum really

https://road.cc/content/feature/105242-beach-slapped

Riders report pressures as low as 4 psi, which means tubeless is sensible, but I think the exact pressure depends on the sand but certainly won't be anywhere close to the pressure you'd run a 32c tyre at.

There are some more tips here

https://fatbikeplanet.com/5-best-fat-bike-tires-for-sand-riding-2020/

Answer (score 1):

Performance of tires on sand mostly depends on tire pressure: The pressure in the tire is almost the same as the pressure that your tire applies to the sand.

32 millimeter tires are generally ridden with pressures around 5 to 6 bar, and that's likely too much for wet sand. Sand may be much stronger when its wet, but 6 kilograms per square centimeter are quite a bit. Unless the sand is of the kind that you find at beaches which are amenable to drive cars on, I wouldn't try with such a slim tire.

That said, if you want to ride your bike on sand and don't want to swap tires, you can reduce its air pressure to the rated minimum. As I said, that pressure is the pressure that you apply to the sand, so minimum air in your tire may allow you to ride on sand that you couldn't cross with high pressure.

Of course, if you want to ride on sand regularly, use the widest tires that will fit your frame. Or buy a mountain bike for this.

Comment: I hope to try this tomorrow with low tide. I can't get my hands on a small pump, so I'll be lugging my full size pump with me... While my frame can take wider tires, I installed (pricey) fenders which can't. So I won't be upgrading to wider tires soon and hope lowering pressure is sufficient